# Facing issue in getting the largest integer from Array

Tags: java

Receiving 5,9,7 as output.. Where as the expected should be only 9..Below is the code:

```
public class GreatestNoInArray {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        int a[]= new int[] {1,2,5,9,7};        
        int big=a[0];        
        for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++){        
            if (big<a[i])        
                big=a[i];                   
            System.out.println(a[i]);        
        }
    }    
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 7):

for expected answer you need to print `big` (not `a[i]`)  out side of loop

Answer (score 4):

```
public class GreatestNoInArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int a[]= new int[] {1,2,5,9,7};
      int big=a[0];

      for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++){
          if (big<a[i])       
              big=a[i];
          }   
      System.out.println(big);
  }
}
```

Comment: How silly was that.. I declared a variable for the largest and m printing i instead.. Thanks a lot mate..

Answer (score 0):

code should be like this:

```
public class GreatestNoInArray {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        int a[] = new int[] {1,2,5,9,7};        
        int big = a[0];        
        for (int i=1; i<a.length; i++){        
            if (big < a[i])        
                big = a[i];                   
            //System.out.println(a[i]);        
        }
    System.out.println("Big: " + big);
    }    
}
```

This works!